# Python: Sending email with attachment only with the stdlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to send an email with attachment (for example a text file) with python. Is this possible with the stdlib or do I have to download and install other packages?

I would like to do this with the stdlib.

thx. :)

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Yes.:

import smtplib
 
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login('email', 'pw')
 
msg = "TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST"

server.send
server.sendmail("emailfrom", "emailto", msg)
server.quit()

But I want to send this with a attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Open a plain text file for reading.  For this example, assume that
# the text file contains only ASCII characters.
fp = open(textfile, 'rb')
# Create a text/plain message
msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()

# me == the sender's email address
# you == the recipient's email address
msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' % textfile
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Send the message via our own SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

Comment: This is not working for me:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled.py", line 11, in <module>
    msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/mime/text.py", line 34, in __init__
    _text.encode('us-ascii')
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: @dosen get a simple text file, and load it `open("testfile.txt", 'rb')`